# Substitute sender email address with a name in Apache commons email

Tags: java, email, smtp, apache-commons, apache-commons-email

Is there a way to show sender's name instead of an e-mail address when sending an e-mail?

This is what I'm currently doing :

```
Email email = new HtmlEmail().setStartTLSRequired(true);
    email.setDebug(false);
    email.setHostName("smtp.test.ch");
    email.setSmtpPort(587);
    email.setAuthentication("***", "***");
    email.setFrom("testemail@test.ch");
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setMsg(message);
    email.addTo(to);
    email.send();
```

So I'd like to substitute "testemail@test.ch" with the name.

Thanks,

Comment: How using `setFrom(String email, String name)` where `name` is personal name of sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting sender's email as below.

```
 email.setFrom("John Doe<testemail@test.ch>");
```

This will show the name of sender as John Doe in receiver's inbox.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Doc...
there are 3 `Email.setFrom(...)` methods 
[image: JavaDoc]
and you are using the wrong one.